Argument-containing register notation after argument renaming [radare2]
I'm currently reverse-engineering a game, and I need useful register notations after function args renaming. Like that:
lea rsi, [var_10h]                    ; const char *s                 <-- I NEED THIS
mov edx, 4                            ; std::size_t count             <-- I NEED THIS
mov rdi, r12                          ; file_compressorst& fc_obj     <-- I NEED THIS
call sym file_compressorst::write_file(void*, long) ; file_compressorst::write_file_2

Unfortunately, I can achieve this only executing aaaa two times: before args renaming and after. And even in that case:

it works eventually;
fcn.* argument changes reset, and I get register notations only for sym.*.

What I've tried
I found out that aaaa command is actually a macro for:
aa
af@@@i
af@ entry0
af@@@s
afva@@@F
aac
aar
avrr
af @@ method.*
afva@@@F
aaft
aanr
/azs
aap
e anal.types.constraint = true

I tried every command listed above separately in case it helps to get the desired result. But none of that worked. And docs are not as helpful as I want.
What am I not seeing that I need to see?
Could someone help me with that?

Versions:
radare2 5.9.3 0 @ linux-x86-64
birth: git.5.9.3 2024-07-17__21:49:23
commit: 5.9.3
options: gpl release -O? cs:5 cl:2 make

